# Ruby tool that pics a folder on the local drive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, directory, stdin

Ok so i have a ruby script that currently prompts the user for a string location of a folder on the users harddrive ...this works well

```
  puts "\nEnter the location of the files"
loop do
  print "\nLocation: "
  reply = ''
  reply = STDIN.gets.strip
  break if File.directory?(reply)
  puts File.directory?(reply)
end
```

But i was wondering if there was another tool other then the STDIN (which currently makes the user enter a string of the path) that will popup a folder search that the user can navigate to ...if there is anything else I can provide for anyone to help you help me..

I can ever use rails if there is no other option but i have no idea whats available to me

Answer (score 3):

There are a [many Ruby GUI libraries](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/GUI_Toolkit_Modules); pick one--most will have a file dialog.

Comment: I found what i need in FXRUBY but i dont know how to use it...this is the function i need (getOpenDirectory (Fox::FXFileDialog))....would this be like a require 'fxruby' or something like that

Comment: @Tamer There's an entire user's guide with examples; did you look at any of those?

Answer (score 0):

For simple dialogs, [Zenity](http://library.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/zenity-introduction.html.en) is fine.
This is a file selection dialog:

```
file = `zenity --file-selection --title="Select a file"`.chomp
```

Adding one parameter changes it to a directory selection dialog:

```
dir  = `zenity --file-selection --directory --title="Select a directory"`.chomp
```